# Google Cloud Tasks - How to secure HTTP POST request?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, post, https, google-cloud-tasks

I've been working with **Google Cloud Tasks** in one of my App, I used **Google Cloud Tasks** for events scheduling to respond in UI after event status changes if a particular scheduled time is reached and the task is dispatched.

And, I find out there was an issue with the **HTTP POST request**, it was not totally secured. I found on internet that, anyone with just internet connection and my payload pattern data can request to this **HTTP POST request** and can manipulate my document in firestore.

That was my `task` object, the part of `onCreate` trigger which I used to create task in the queue.

```
const task {
   name: `${taskName}/myTask-${snapshot.id}-${expireSeconds}`,
   httpRequest: {
     httpMethod: ‘POST’,
     url: `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/schedulerCallback?eventId=${snapshot.id}`,
     body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString(‘base64’),
     headers: { ‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’ }
  }
   scheduleTime: {
     seconds: expirationAtSeconds
  }
}
```

To create the task:

```
await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task });
```

And that was the HTTP `onRequest` Trigger, dispatched on scheduleTime arrives.

```
export const schedulerCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
   // accessing the eventId that we sent over HTTP POST request as a query param.
   const eventId = req.query.eventId as string;
   try {
      await admin.firestore().collection(“events”).doc(eventId).delete();
   } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      res.status(500).send(e);
   }
});
```

I was so frustrated of that, and wasn't found any solution for securing that HTTP POST request. I came here in stack overflow, here were some similar questions asked before but was out of my context. That was not related to specifically securing HTTP POST request with Google Cloud Tasks.

After putting all of my effort and so many research, I, finally find out the solution for that. And I'm happy to share it with you, See the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Securing an HTTP request is a solvable problem, so we don't need to worry about it.
Here's how you will do it:

First of all, before going through creating tasks and then to deal with them. You need a service account, with certain roles. And so using that service account authenticate the function invoker and allow only that service account to do all the stuff such as, Invoke Cloud Functions trigger, Create Service Account Tokens, and finally to enqueue tasks to the queue.

Having this in mind, Create a service account by going to [IAM & Admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/) > Service Accounts. On the top menu you will see **CREATE SERVICE ACCOUNT**. Name your service account and go for **CREATE AND CONTINUE**. In the second step give the following roles to the service accounts (Cloud Function Invoker, Cloud Tasks Enqueuer, and Service Account Token Creator) and you are done with the service account.

Next, on IAM & Admin come to the first tab named IAM. Click **Grant Access** and in the first field “New principals” add your service account there and grant the above roles to it and save it.

Now, in your `onCreate` Trigger add one additional field just like that:

```
const serviceAccountEmail = 'YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_HERE';
```

Next your `task` object configuration is gonna look like this:

```
const task {
    name: `${taskName}/myTask-${snapshot.id}-${expireSeconds}`,
      httpRequest: {
    httpMethod: ‘POST’,
    url: `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/schedulerCallback?eventId=${snapshot.id}`,
    body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString(‘base64’),
       headers: { ‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’ }
    }
   oidcToken: {
     serviceAccountEmail,
     audience: “https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/schedulerCallback”
   }
     scheduleTime: {
     seconds: expirationAtSeconds
  }
}
```

After you have set up the service account and configured task with the `oidcToken`, everytime, when `onCreate` function triggers, the Google Cloud Tasks receive the instructions on who should make the HTTP request and where it should be sent.

The `audience` field is specified same as the `httpRequest` url (excluding query params). The main purpose of this is to verify that the token was intended for the target service (our cloud function in this case).

When the scheduled time arrives and the task is about to be dispatched, the service account specified `serviceAccountEmail` field is used to generate an OpenID Connect (OIDC) token. This token claims about the identity of the service account, including the  `audience` claim that matches your Cloud Function’s URL.

The OIDC token is sent as part of the HTTP request’s Authorization header when the task is fully dispatched. When your Cloud Function receives the request, it can validate the token to ensure that the request is authenticated and authorized. It verifies the `audience` claim matches its own URL, confirming that the token was intended for this service.

Next, create an asynchronous function to verify token:

```
async function verifyToken(token: string, location: any,project: any) {
    const client = new OAuth2Client();
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: token,
        audience: `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/updateEventStatus`,
    });

    return ticket.getPayload();
}
```

The function above uses, `OAuth2Client` so you need to install & import `google-auth-library`.

```
// install library
$ npm install google-auth-library
// import library
import { OAuth2Client } from “google-auth-library”;
```

Now your `schedulerCallback` is gonna look like this:

```
export const schedulerCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
   // add the projectID and location
   const project = json.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG!).projectId;
   const location = ‘us-central1’;
   const eventId = req.query.eventId as string;

   // access the headers > authorization of the request
    const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  // check if authorization header is not null
   if(!authorizationHeader) {
      res.status(401).send(“unauthorized token”);
      return;
   }

   // if authorizationHeader is not null access the token
    const token = authorizationHeader.split(‘ ’)[1];

   // verify ID token
    try {
      await verifyIdToken(token, location, project);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(401).send(“Unauthorized token”);
      return;
    }

   // delete document
   try {
      await admin.firestore().collection(“events”).doc(eventId).delete();
   } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      res.status(500).send(e);
   }
});
```

With this done, now your HTTP POST request is secured, and no one outisde having just an internet connection can manipulate the document in your firestore. But only your app has the right to do it.

Learn more about **Google Cloud Task** scheduling by following step by step guide in [my Medium blog post](https://medium.com/@ak187429/enablschedule-cloud-functions-with-cloud-tasks-for-document-ttl-part-1-2c110f0576cd).

Enjoy!